# how to config spring security with !hasRole()

Tags: spring, security, config

my config

```
<!-- NON AUTHENTICATION PAGES -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/about" access="permitAll" />

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/admin/user/changepass/**" access="permitAll" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/admin/user/changepass/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />        
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/mochaUser/getUser/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/mochaUser/getUser/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_DEV')" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/user/userblock/add" access="!hasRole('ROLE_FO')" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/user/userblock/delete" access="!hasRole('ROLE_FO')" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/user/userblock/edit" access="!hasRole('ROLE_FO')" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/user/userblock/add" access="!hasRole('ROLE_BO')" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/user/userblock/edit" access="!hasRole('ROLE_BO')" />
```

what wrong? why `!hasRole()` not working, I still visit the link in `!hasRole()`.
Sorry if my english no good
thanks

Comment: What is your expectation? I read for example the rule <sec:intercept-url pattern="/user/userblock/delete" access="!hasRole('ROLE_FO')" /> so: If user has not the role 'ROLE_FO' MAY ACCESS to /user/userblock/delete. So everyone who has not the role 'ROLE_FO'  may access to this resource. Are you sure you testing with a user, which has the role 'ROLE_FO' ?

Comment: i want users has role "ROLE_FO" or "ROLE_BO" 
not accessible for link in parttern .i was test with user has the role 'ROLE_FO' but still visit link /user/userblock/delete

Comment: or how to config ROLE access only a link? Thank u/